# SSIS ETL overflow using BigInt, data is one digit too large

Tags: ssis, etl, bigint

I have an ETL SSIS project where the number of digits is one digit too large for Bigint. I get this overflow problem running the dtx package because of such and the data cannot transfer.

The data is flowing from a flat file to a data warehouse as BigInt.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this?

If I reduce one digit the package runs fine. I was wondering how do I save that one digit and add it into the database or what is the best course of action?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

From what I read:

```
 A BIGINT is always 8 bytes and can store -9223372036854775808 to 
 9223372036854775807 (signed) or 0 to 18446744073709551615 (unsigned).
```

If you have more digits than that, how do you handle this in the SSIS package?

What I think: Maybe create a derived column in the database table for only that digit and separate that digit from the original data? How would you do such?

Answer (score 1):

Could you store it as a Decimal (or a Double)?

Comment: You cannot change the beginning or end datatype, because the company will not allow me to do such. I was thinking, I can separate the last digit into another derived column for an extended length. If I do %10, then it will give me the last digit. Then I extract the last digit into that column during the processing. Though, not sure how to go about it.

Comment: What I mean is that you could store it in SSIS as a Decimal, so you could cast it as you pull it in, and then deal with it in a similar way at the other end, e.g., in a Staging table (or perhaps it would go straight in, I haven't tested it).

Comment: Data in the database is datatype BigInt. It won't take that many digits, so I think the best way is to remove the last digit while keeping the row and place it into it's own column.

Comment: I'd bring it up with the company - they're wanting to store data larger than bigint in a bigint field?

Comment: I totally agree and have talked to them, but they won't let me change the datatype (it sucks). But, I did think you could create a derived column for the integers that overflow.

Comment: There are many ways to do it in SSIS (casting as a Decimal, for example), but wouldn't you also need a way to store it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Use either a decimal or a varchar.